# How can I use a set with diffrent members as indexs?

Tags: julia, julia-jump

Pleas help me. I want to use a set by not order elements as indexes of some

variables. for example

I have 
    s=[2,3]

```
@constraint(ILRP,c7[ k=1:2,t=1:4],sum(x[i,j,k,t] for i=[2,3],

j=[2,3])<=size(s,1)-1)'
```

for index I ,j I want to use [2,3] as indexes. and I get for example this constraint:

```
x[2][2][k][t]+x[2][3][k][t]+x[3][2][k][t]+x[3][3][k][t]<=1
```

Thanks very much.

Comment: your constraint works correctly. What problem do you have?

Comment: I have a set
    S=[[1, 2], [1, 3], [2, 3], [1, 2, 3]]

I want use this set as indexes of my constraints. I coded that as follow:
    
    for i=1:size(S,1)
       a=size(S[i],1);
       b=S[i]
       @constraint(ILRP,c7[ k=1:2,t=1:4],sum(x[i,j,k,t] for i=b, j=b)<=a-1)
    end
 
Thanks for your help.

Comment: This also looks good.

Comment: only it takes time. how can I don't use loop for this constraint?

Comment: `@constraint(ILRP,c7[i=axes(S,1), k=1:2,t=1:4],sum(x[i,j,k,t] for i=S[i], j=S[i])<=length(S[i]-1)` should work but I have not checked.

Comment: it is really useful. and it promotes my code. I am really thankful. but it has this error
ERROR: MethodError: no method matching  
start(::AxisArrays.Axis{:row,Base.OneTo{Int64}})

Comment: Can you please post a fully reproducible example as you seem to be using non standard arrays from a package.

Comment: I couldn't post my code here. Because it is too long. Please if you could, say me another way that I can post my code for you. 
thank you for your kindly help.

Comment: I used

"using JuMP,CPLEX,Combinatorics,Images"

in top section. is that correct? should I use Images for axes()?

Comment: The easiest way to share larger portions of code is via https://gist.github.com/. You might try to convert images crated by Images to standard matrices (probably it is not needed, but Images can use custom indexing and it is a more advanced topic that).

Comment: Thanks very much Prof. Kamiński . I registered there and placed the code.

Comment: can you add a link?

Comment: sure. 
https://gist.github.com/soma903/459673eb112006aec1576896893a0106

Comment: In this case `axes` should work as `S` is a standard array. I think that if you are not able to resolve it from this point it is better to switch to a chat-mode (e.g. ask a question on discourse).

Comment: Thanks very much  :)